# How to properly show a login screen on top of previous views in an iPhone app with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm quite new to SwiftUI, so I would appreciate your help. I have an application whose data is private and requires a login screen. I want the login screen to be shown every time the app goes to the background, but I need the app to keep the state (i.e, if the user was in the middle of creating a new item and changes to another app, I want all the data he has typed to be kept, I can live with the data being lost if the app is killed but I want to allow to swap momentarily between apps to let the user copy and paste data between apps).

I've been googlin for a solution and people is implementing the login screen with a regular view and showing it based on certain state variable, but I find this approach not working well because:

- Either the state is not kept when the user changes to another app
- Or if the .fullScreenCover modifier is used, the state is kept but does not work well if you are presenting views with the sheet modifier (basically, the loginscren is rendered behing the sheet, which is still shown to the user when he brings the app back to front).

I've read in a post (although it does not show any code example) that the way to go is go have another scene with the loginScreen and switch between scenes, but I'm not able to implement it with SwiftUI.

So far I've tried to implement it by having my app to have two WindowGroup, one with the app contents and another with the login screen. Like the following:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup("MainScene") {
            MainView()
        }
        WindowGroup("LoginScene") {
            LoginScreenView()
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not finding how to change between scenes.

Comment: Showing a login screen is probably best done "near" the root of your view hierarchy. Note that presenting (aka showing it modally) a sheet view will require an existing UIViewController under the hood of SwiftUI - and this has the unfortunate consequences, that more than _one_ component may want to present a view - say an alert, or another sheet, but one ViewController can only ever present _one_ other view at the same time. So, keep this in mind - means, have a clear picture of your view hierarchy and get to know where the view controllers are. ;)

Comment: You don't want the login screen in a separate window, because "authentication" is a modal, i.e. _requires_ user interaction. With different windows, a user can switch to either window, which does not solve your problem. You need a "modal" (i.e. "sheet") in all windows which require authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As far as I understood, an iPhone app cannot have separate windows, so having a second WindowGroup would not be an issue (but I cannot find a way to switch between them). Is that assumption correct? On the other hand, if I go with the modal approach, I cannot find any view presentation that is rendered on top of a sheet. Should I avoid using sheet at all?

Comment: Looking what other applications are doing, I see that Enpass (the password manager) does precisely what I want. It shows a login screen on top of the views are presenting, and that login screen even renders  on top of a view presented with the sheet modifier, so that is possible. I just need to know how to apprach it.

Comment: You are right that with pure SwiftUI you cannot create more than one custom  scene or more than one window on iOS. You could still try to programmatically manages scenes,  with something utilising `activateSceneSession(for:errorHandler:)`.  However, semantically an own non-modal login window would not be an appropriate solution - on neither OS. You want to prevent the user to interact with an UI when he/she needs to authenticate. With SwiftUI you would use a sheet.  So, this is more a question where you provide the state that tells the view to render the sheet.

Comment: I've tried calling the activateSceneSession, and although I'm not sure i'm calling it correctly (as I do not see how to pass the scene to activate), I'm getting the following error: "Cannot request scene session activation because it is not supported on the current device.", which makes me think that this method is not supported on iPhone.

Comment: As pointed out already, I would not try to show a separate logging window - no matter whether you are running on macOS, iPad or iOS. Instead, you should show a (modal) sheet on every window that requires authentication. You can make this "login state" global for the app, though. I posted an answer, similar to @burnsi 's, with focus on the principle that a view is "a function of state". It's occurs somewhat convoluted, but it inevitably requires this stuff for a minimal viable solution for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can´t have multiple `WindowGroup`´s in a single app. Please refer to [this WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10061/) video on what top app container you can choose from and what they do.

As already mentioned in the comments this comes down to application state no more no less. You can observe changes to the `scenePhase` environment property and set the state accordingly.

e.g.:

```
// pull the scenePhase var from the environment
@Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
// this will hold the login state of the application
@State private var login: Bool = false

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        Group{
            if login{
                // if the user is logged in show the content
                ContentView()
            } else{
                // Here should be some view with appropriate logic
                Button("login"){
                    login = true
                }
            }
        }
        // observe all scenePhase changes and invalidate the login
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newValue in
            login = false
        }
    }
}
```

In the `ContentView` this now comes down to persisting the previous state. You can use `@SceneStorage` or `@AppStorage` to persist the values you want to be shown again. As you didn´t mention how you navigate or show these views I could only speculate. I provided 2 examples on how you could implement this.

1. with a `NavigationStack`:

   ```
    struct ContentView: View {
       @SceneStorage("navigation") var path: [String] = []

        var body: some View {
            NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                Button("subView"){
                    path.append("subView")
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { value in
                    if value == "subView"{
                        SubView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct SubView: View {
        // persist the values with @SceneStorage
        @SceneStorage("text1") private var text1: String = ""
        @SceneStorage("text2") private var text2: String = ""

        var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Text("subView")
                TextField("", text: $text1)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .padding()
                TextField("", text: $text2)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }

    // this extension is used to store an array of any Codable in UserDefaults
    extension Array: RawRepresentable where Element: Codable{
        public typealias RawValue = String
        // encode the array or save empty array if it fails
        public var rawValue: RawValue{
            guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self), let coded = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
                return "[]"
            }

            return coded
        }
        // decode the string to an array or empty if it fails
        public init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
            guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8), let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data) else {
                self = []
                return
            }

            self = decoded
        }
    }
   ```
2. with a sheet that shows `SubView`. Here we need to store the value for showing and hiding the sheet our selves. SwiftUI will set the value to `false` when dismissing or moving the view to the background.

   ```
    struct ContentView: View {
        // load the saved value from UserDefaults
        @State private var showSheet: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sheet")

        var body: some View {
            Button("show sheet"){
                showSheet = true
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
                SubView()
            })
            .onChange(of: showSheet) { newValue in
                // store changed value to UserDefaults
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: "sheet")
            }
        }
    }
   ```

This is of course just a crude implementation and could use a lot of refinement. But it should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I've finally gone down the route proposed by burnsi, although I want to thank also to @CocouchDeveloper for his help. Both have contributed to my undestanding of the problem and to its solution. The reason why I've chosen the burnsi approach is because the sheet approach does not convince me for a login page, and burnsi also introduces the concept of SceneStorage which is very helpful. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

This implements a simple solution for a login window which shows the view part, but leaves the actual implementation of the domain logic left to the OP.

The solution assumes, you are using a single global "AppState", and you manage this state in "Reducers" or "Models".

The Login view will be presented within a sheet, which is actually presented at the very root view controller of the app. You can use the "View Debugger" in Xcode to take a look.

**Caveat**

As already pointed out in my comments, there might be child views which may want to present their own views, which happens to be presented on this very root view controller as well. In order to avoid conflicts you should ensure, that child views are located on top of another UIViewController, for example when using a `NavigationStack`, SwiftUI inserts a UIViewController by itself. Use Xcode's "View Debugger" to get a glimpse how these view controllers will be built into the modern SwiftUI view hierarchy.

**Note**

In order to build an app, replace the "App.swift" file generated from the Xcode template with this file.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct User {
    var name: String
}

struct AuthenticationError: LocalizedError {
    var errorDescription: String? {
        return NSLocalizedString("Authentication failed", comment: "AuthenticationError")
    }
}

func signIn(name: String, password: String) async -> Result<User, Login.Error> {
    do {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(1000))
        if name == "John Appleseed" && password == "123" {
            return .success(User(name: name))
        } else {
            return .failure(Login.Error(underlyingError: AuthenticationError()))
        }
    } catch {
        return .failure(.init(underlyingError: error))
    }
}


struct AppState {
    var contentState: Content.State = .init()
    var loginState: Login.State? = .some(.init())
    var user: User = .init(name: "")
}

@main
struct LoginWindowDemoApp: App {
    
    @State private var appState: AppState = .init()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(state: appState.contentState)
            .sheet(item: $appState.loginState) {
                print("loging screen dismissed")
            } content: { loginState in
                Login.ContentView(
                    initialName: appState.user.name,
                    error: loginState.error,
                    isProgressing: loginState.isProgressing,
                    submit: { name, password in
                        // Note: in production you would send this intent to an
                        // "event actor" (aka Model, aka Store, aka ViewModel)
                        // which would perform side effects, compute the logic
                        // and mutate the state. The view just _observes_ the
                        // state, renders it accordingly, and sends intents to
                        // this event actor.
                        //
                        // eventActor.send(.signIn(name: name, password: password)
                        
                        self.appState.loginState?.isProgressing = true
                        
                        Task {
                            let result = await signIn(name: name, password: password)
                            switch result {
                            case .success(let authenticatedUser):
                                appState.user = authenticatedUser
                                appState.loginState = nil
                             case .failure(let error):
                                self.appState.loginState?.error = error
                            }
                            self.appState.loginState?.isProgressing = false
                        }
                    },
                    alertConfirmed: {
                        self.appState.loginState?.error = nil
                    }
                )
                .interactiveDismissDisabled()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The Login Use Case.

The `Login.Content` view provides the name and the password field and a button which should invoke a sign-in attempt. When authentication fails, the parent will provide an error which will be rendered accordingly.

Note this view is purely driven by state. It does not perform any logic by itself. Instead it sends user intents back to the parent via closures.

```
enum Login {
    
    struct State: Identifiable {
        let id: Int = 0
        var name: String = ""
        var password: String = ""
        var error: Error? = nil
        var isProgressing: Bool = false
    }
    
    enum Event {
        case submit(user: User, password:String)
        case cancel
    }
    
    struct Error: LocalizedError {
        var underlyingError: Swift.Error
        
        var errorDescription: String? {
            underlyingError.localizedDescription
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        
        enum Field: Hashable {
            case username
            case password
        }

        let initialName: String
        let error: Error?
        let isProgressing: Bool
        let submit: (_ name: String, _ passord: String) -> Void
        let alertConfirmed: () -> Void
        
        @SwiftUI.State private var username = ""
        @SwiftUI.State private var password = ""
        @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?

        
        var body: some View {
            
            let alertBinding = Binding(
                get: { error != nil },
                set: { _ in }
            )
            
            NavigationStack {
                VStack {
                    Form {
                        TextField("Name", text: $username)
                            .focused($focusedField, equals: .username)
                            .padding()
                        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                            .focused($focusedField, equals: .password)
                            .padding()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            focusedField = nil
                            submit(username, password)
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Login")
                        })
                        .padding()
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Login")
            }
            .overlay {
                if isProgressing {
                    ProgressView()
                }
            }
            .disabled(isProgressing)
            .alert(isPresented: alertBinding, error: error) {
                Button("OK") {
                    alertConfirmed()
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                username = initialName
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

You can test the LoginView with previews:

```
#Preview {
    Login.ContentView(
        initialName: "John Appleseed",
        error: nil,
        isProgressing: false,
        submit: { name, password in
            print("login with name: \(name) password: \(password)")
        },
        alertConfirmed: {
            print("alertConfirmed")
        }
    )
}

#Preview {
    Login.ContentView(
        initialName: "John Appleseed",
        error: nil,
        isProgressing: true,
        submit: { name, password in
            print("login with name: \(name) password: \(password)")
        },
        alertConfirmed: {
            print("alertConfirmed")
        }
    )
}

#Preview {
    Login.ContentView(
        initialName: "John Appleseed",
        error: Login.Error(underlyingError: AuthenticationError()),
        isProgressing: false,
        submit: { name, password in
            print("login with name: \(name) password: \(password)")
        },
        alertConfirmed: {
            print("alertConfirmed")
        }
    )
}
```